# Как связать модели из двух микросервисов?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

Есть приложение. Оно состоит из нескольких микросервисов написанных на FastAPI.
Вот структура проекта:

```
|---author
|------__init__.py
|------models.py
|------router.py
|---book
|------__init__.py
|------models.py
|------router.py
|-main.py
|-dockerfile
|-docker-compose.yml
```

Как связать модели сервиса book с моделями сервиса author?

Во всех примерах, где речь идет о связанных моделях, они указываются в одном модуле, но при этом считается хорошим тоном разделять логику в проектах на отдельные пакеты (директории). А если вот я хочу, чтобы мои модели находились в разных пакетах и при этом мне надо их связать.

Пока что у меня вылетает исключение

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper Mapper[Author(Author)], expression 'book.models.Book' failed to locate a name ('book.models.Book'). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'author.models.Author'> class after both dependent classes have been defined

С импортами проблем быть не должно. Такой подход практиковал, когда писал монолитное приложение на Django. Конечно, там свой orm, а тут уже работать надо с алхимией. Как решить данную задачу?

Comment: Вы уж определитесь, что конкретно вы делаете — микросервисы или модули в монолите?

Comment: Ну вообще микросервисы. Начал изучать эту технологию ни так давно. Пока что это два модуля монолитного приложения. И у меня не получается связать модели. Но конечно, после того, как решу проблему со связями, то уже буду писать докер файл для каждого модуля и модули уже будут как отдельные сервисы, если такое можно сделать, связать модели двух микросервисов, которые работают независимо друг от друга.

Comment: Если микросервисы, то между микросервисами не должно быть связи никакой вообще. Единственная допустимая связь между микросервисами — это через какой-нибудь публичный сетевой API (обычно REST или типа того)

Comment: Ну хорошо. Этот момент я уяснил. Сейчас это два модуля монолитного приложения. Как связать модели из разных модулей?